Window current detection through a current sense differential amplifier and a comparator
I'd like to implement a circuit to detect the over-current through a grounded load. The limits for that current are either 3mA DC current or -3mA and 3mA in case of bipolar AC current. I want to generate an alert signal any time the current through the load is outside this range, in order to control a switch that will disconnect the load from the circuit if over-current is detected. As a first approach to implement this, I read that the INA301 component is a good option, as it can be configured for a bidirectional application (as shown in the following image) and generates an alert signal when the current is out of the current range specified.

The problem is that my common-mode input voltage will be between approximately -19.5V (achieved during the negative cycles of the bipolar current signal) and 19.5V, but this component can only handle 0V to 36V positive common-mode voltage (as specified in its datasheet).
Therefore, I've assumed that I cannot use the INA301 for my application. Could you suggest any solutions?
I haven't find similar components with a higher common-mode input voltage range. However, I found a bidirectional current sense amplifier, TSC2011, which could be use for detecting the current through a sense resistor in series with the load, but I don't know how should I then integrate the comparator to generate the alert signal in order to mimic the performance of INA301. What do you think about it?
Thank you so much in advance.
